# Electron Mainprocess Questions

Tags: electron

The quality might be low because it hasn't been long since I studied
I apologize in advance.

This is an example of the concept of a Main process and a Renderer process...

When running as app.on in **index.js** ( Main process ) **auth.js** require (Main process)
auth.js
Through the function of through the browser window
Rendering **login.html** with loadFile.

perform dynamic logic of **login.js** ( Renderer Process ) >>> **login.html, auth.js** Perform and ipc.
It receives the status value from auth.js

Through the login check status value received by **index.js**
Hand over to **main.js** and call **main.html** in main.js.
Did I understand conceptually?

This language is the first time I have experienced it, and it is necessary to construct a development environment through an accurate concept.